# Nexus packages deployment using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nuget, nuget-package, nexus, continuous-deployment

I am trying to automate build and deployment of .Net windows service and SQL server scripts using Jenkins.

For .Net windows service, I am able to use MSBuild to create release exe/dlls. I have zipped the release folder and uploaded to Nexus.

For SQL server scripts, I have started using SSDT and able to create .dacpac file. I am also able to generate deployment script for a specific server using the .dacpac file. I have uploaded the .dacpac file to Nexus.

I am not sure what the best practices to deploy .Net artifacts from Nexus. I have the following questions:

1. How do I deploy .net Nexus packages? (do I unzip them and use
   InstallUtil to install the service?)
2. How do I deploy sql .dacpac Nexus package? (do I unzip the
   package and use SQLPackage to generate a script for the target
   database server?)

Are there any better ways to deploy .Net Nexus packages?

Answer (score 0):

Use NuGet packages and upload NuGet packages to nexus.

1. create a NuGet package using `nuget pack` command. You can do
   this part of your msbuild
2. Push the above created NuGet package to
   Nexus using `nuget push` command.

Here is the link about how to setup .Net Package repositories in Nexus

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/.net-package-repositories-with-nuget

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to do NuGet packages. How can I use these NuGet packages to 1) install on the window service 2) deploy sql? Do I need to unzip them and do it manually?

Comment: You should use `nuget restore` to restore the nuget packages. But i am not sure what do you mean by install on the windows service?